# Python Alpha Sort a List

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list from 1 to 25. Right now it's properly sorted form 1 to 25 but I need it sorted like this:

```
[1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20, .. etc]
```

I can't find anything online that would allow me to do that. Thanks.

Comment: `sorted(yourlist, key=str)` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>>l = range(1,26)
>>>sorted(l, key=str)
[1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, `[i for i in range(1,26)]` was just silly :)